# How many maximum device can we pair via Bluetooth to android device at a time?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can anyone tell me how many maximum devices can we pair via Bluetooth to android devices at a time.....i googled every where but i didn't get the right answer.

Answer (score 11):

In a Bluetooth piconet one master can communicate up to 7 active slaves, there can be some other up to 248 devices which are in sleep mode (may participate to communication actively when another active device goes into sleep mode).

In Bluetooth scatternets (interconnected piconets) number of devices are not limited. Some slaves used as a bridge by participating two or more piconets. One of the most advanced topology defined for Bluetooth scatternets is Cube Connected Cycles architecture.

you can set up multiple bluetooth connections (at least RFCOMM connections). Just use a alternative thread for you connection, and it would work fine (I guess) See also: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

something like this,

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

Comment: Hi blganesh101 ..thanks for your reply..Can you forward me some other link..if possible

Comment: check this out  

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/adeBD275u30